# Select enum type in inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity I have a C# class that's serialized, so I can present it's public variables in the inspector for a scriptable object. One variable is referring to an enum elsewhere in a static class. The enum is very long and I would prefer to break it into many shorter enums. Is there any way to select the type of the enum without having to write many variations of the serialized class I'm using to display in the inspector?

For example lets say I split the large enum into 3 - call them eA, eB and eC. Is there a way in the inspector to specify that the enum I want to use is for example eB, without having to have three different serialized classes each containing a variable for a different enum?

As a further illustration here is the actual inspector. I would like to select a TakeOverNeutralTurf or TakeOverEnemyTurf enum, then be able to select it's values, instead of having one long enum with those prefixes:

[image]

I guessed reflection might help but can't see a way to make it work.

Comment: You might try extracting the relation flag (Neutral/Enemy in your example) to the separate property to simplify the enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The enum is very long and I would prefer to break it into many shorter enums.

Unity has a cool semi built-in feature for this already.

1. Simply name your enums and use `_` for grouping them in "menues" (you seem to already have this)
2. Then have a custom property drawer replacing that `_` by a `/`

Example:

```
public ExampleEnum exampleEnum;

public enum ExampleEnum
{
    Some_Large_Value,
    Some_Other_Value
}

#if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(ExampleEnum))]
public class ExamplePropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    private readonly GUIContent[] options = Enum.GetNames(typeof(ExampleEnum)).Select(x => new GUIContent(x.Replace("_", "/"))).ToArray();
        
    public override float GetPropertyHeight(SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        return EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight;
    }

    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        var current = property.enumValueIndex;
        var selected = EditorGUI.Popup(position, label, current, options);
        property.enumValueIndex = selected;
        
        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }
}
#endif
```

[image]